# Raphael.d.ts compilation issues

Tags: typescript

I have obtained the raphael d.ts file from nuget.  But failure ensues from line 247 onwards when i use this file with complaints about getcolor.

I presume I have forgotten something.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** You can get the latest file here which my pull request merged 
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/raphael/raphael.d.ts

It should have been :

```
getColor:{
    (value?: number): string;
    reset();
};
```

instead of

```
getColor {
    (value?: number): string;
    reset();
};
```

Comment: Hi, I agree with your answer, this is the fix I applied myself.  I guess my real puzzlement is that no one else had encountered this issue before me and that such a show stopper was placed on an 'official' location at all and then not fixed asap.